# Error using legappend()

Tags: matlab, plot

I am writing a function that iterates through a loop and adds entries to a plot. When I try to use `legappend()`, though, I get the error below. I am passing it a string variable.

```
Error using legend>process_inputs (line 526)
Invalid argument. Type 'help legend' for more information.

Error in legend>make_legend (line 303)
[orient,location,position,children,listen,strings,propargs] =
process_inputs(ha,argin); %#ok

Error in legend (line 257)
    [~,msg] = make_legend(ha,args(arg:end),version);

Error in legappend (line 74)
    [legend_h,object_h,plot_h,text_strings] = legend(h,allDatah,str);
```

Here is a minimal example, taken from the [MATLAB site](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/community/11255-legappend)

```
% Some data and old models:
x = (1:10)';
y = [x-5+x.^1.05 x-2 x-3 x-4 x-5];

% Plot the data and old models:
figure
plot(x,y(:,1),'mo','markersize',10);
hold on;
plot(x,y(:,2),'r');
plot(x,y(:,3),'b');
plot(x,y(:,4),'k');
plot(x,y(:,5),'kp');
box off
axis([1 10 -5 20])

legend('data','model 1','model 2','model 3','model 4','location','northwest')
legend boxoff

myNewModel = x - 5.5 + x.^1.1;
plot(x,myNewModel,'m','linewidth',2);

legappend('my new amazing model!')
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47228-legappend

Comment: As a user of relatively high rep, you should honestly know enough to provide a [mcve]...

Comment: Fair enough. I've added the example from the MATLAB site https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/community/11255-legappend

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: R2016a (9.0.0.341360). I just installed it yesterday.

Comment: MATLAB's graphics engine was significantly overhauled in R2014b. `legappend`, as currently written, is not compatible. Until the author (or someone else) can update the code for the new engine you're going to have to look at alternatives or just generate the legend manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, [MATLAB's graphics engine was significantly overhauled in R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-changes-in-r2014b.html). While it brought a plethora of very welcome changes, like any major code overhaul it broke functionality in the existing code base. Relevant here is [implementing legends as their own object class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-colorbars-and-legends-not-valid-axes-handles.html) rather than as a cobbled together `axes` object. Given its July 2014 release date, [`legappend`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47228-legappend) was likely created using R2014a and the logic in the code assumes that the [`legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) is an `axes` object. This unfortunately breaks in the new graphics system.

Fortunately, the fix isn't as complex as I was anticipating. If you take a look at the [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend-properties.html) of the new `legend` object, there's no documented property for the linked data. Attempting to set the `'String'` property manually also has no effect. However, if you look at the final syntax in the function description (`[l,icons,plots,txt] = legend(___)`), it seems clear that `legend` has a way to access the appropriate internal properties. And indeed, if you poke around in the `legend` source, you'll find the `'PlotChildren'` property, which is an array of object handles.

Putting it all together we get something like the following:

```
function legappend_HG2(newStrings)
% Quick & dirty fork of legappend specific to MATLAB versions >= R2014b
% Only supports appending strings to the existing legend handle
% Assumes only one legend is in the current figure
% Add multiple strings by passing it a 1D cell array of strings

% Find our legend object
h = findobj(gcf, 'Type', 'legend');

if ~isempty(h)
    % Get existing array of legend strings and append our new strings to it
    oldstr = h.String;
    if ischar(newStrings)
        % Input string is a character array, assume it's a single string and
        % dump into a cell
        newStrings = {newStrings};
    end

    newstr = [oldstr newStrings];

    % Get line object handles
    ploth = flipud(get(gca, 'Children'));

    % Update legend with line object handles & new string array
    h.PlotChildren = ploth;
    h.String = newstr;
end
end
```

Swapping `legappend` for `legappend_HG2` in the above MWE we get the desired result:

[image: yay]

Answer (score -1):

Was getting wrong result in R2016b for [exkaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza)'s solution. Hence changed the code in a line a little bit.

```
function legappend_HG2(newStrings)
% Quick & dirty fork of legappend specific to MATLAB versions >= R2016b
% Only supports appending strings to the existing legend handle
% Assumes only one legend is in the current figure
% Add multiple strings by passing it a 1D cell array of strings

% Find our legend object
h = findobj(gcf, 'Type', 'legend');

if ~isempty(h)
    % Get existing array of legend strings and append our new strings to it
    oldstr = h.String;
    %disp(oldstr);
    if ischar(newStrings)
        % Input string is a character array, assume it's a single string and
        % dump into a cell
        newStrings = {newStrings};
    end

    newstr = [oldstr newStrings];
    %disp(newstr);
    % Get line object handles
    ploth = flipud(get(gca, 'Children'));

    % Update legend with line object handles & new string array
    %h.PlotChildren =  ploth;
    h.PlotChildren = [h.PlotChildren; ploth];
    h.String = newstr;
end
end
```

Comment: Maybe you can add which line you changed and why?

Comment: This destroys the previous legend, at least in R2020b. sco1's code still works perfectly fine